# Hosting Jekyll to Namecheap. Works locally but not when uploaded online

Tags: hosting, jekyll

I've got a jekyll install that I'm trying to upload online. It works locally, but when visiting [the site](http://vitaliyg.com), it appears broken.

Here's what I've got in my _config.yml:

```
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "http://vitaliyg.com" # the base hostname & protocol for your site
```

I can't help but think it's something wrong here.
The console isn't pulling up any errors, but my css is missing as well as the template elements like the footer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I had done some research, and I had seen people recommend to only upload the contents of the "_site" folder. Is this the only way? Right now, I've got the whole project folder uploaded into public_html

Comment: Are you uploading your site to each host? Namecheap itself? Or just your domain is hosted there? Anyway, if your web server does not build Jekyll then you'll have to upload just the content of your `_site` folder. I use GitHub Pages to host my Jekyll websites and sometimes the links are broken, so I need to hardcode the paths. For example, instead of `href="css/styles.css"` I'd write `href= {{ site.url }} /css/styles.css" ` Got it?

Comment: Happy new year to you! That was exactly the thing. My host did not build jekyll and I had to upload the contents of _site folder into the root for it to properly work. Thanks for your tip!

Comment: Glad to have helped! ;)